# Hbase Get Complexity when reading from a column

Tags: database, performance, time, nosql, hbase

I understand that get by rowkey in HBase is approximately O(1). What about the time complexity when we try to get a specific column with a row key? 
i.e. what is the time complexity for the below command:

```
get 'table name', 'rowid', {COLUMN ⇒ 'column family:column name'}
```

Are the columns in the rowkey arranged in LinkedList or another HashMap?